# Deploy grails as Tomcat Root

Tags: grails, deployment, config

I have been deploying my webapp with `<app-name>.war` in my case `tao.war`.
Now I need to deploy it in the `tomcat ROOT`.

So I was renaming `tao.war` in `ROOT.war`. Everything seemed to work but when I was editing a domain class respective update was done in the DB but I got forwarded to

```
localhost:8080/tao/person/show/1
```

where I was expecting

```
localhost:8080/person/show/1
```

without the `app-name`.

**Where does the app-name in the URL come from? Where am I missing something.**

Comment: I've never had that problem, you might have the path hardcoded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
grails.app.context = '/'
```

in `Config.groovy`.

Enjoy.